# Is my computer affected if I accidentally create an infinite loop?

Tags: python, macos

This may seem like a dumb question, but I haven't found an answer in regards to this. I was coding a loop in Python using Sublime Text, and I accidentally set the incorrect conditions that lead to running an infinite loop.

After multiple bad attempts, I've noticed that my OS is slower. I was wondering if running loops would negatively harm the RAM or processing even though if I force quit the application - or maybe it was a coincidental occurrence.

Comment: While your program is running it uses CPU time and RAM resources. When you killed it (task manager - Windows, kill -9 - Linux) - it's gone and nothing you should worry about, You can NOT harm ram, unless you're really know how to do it , so don't be worry about it

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry. Vaguely speaking, the CPU in your computer is always running whether you're running your application code or not. And the RAM chip is always powered on as long as the computer is running.
Actually, a DDR memory has to be periodically refreshed in order to work  (think of this as periodic read-write cycles, although they're carried out by the chip itself. 
So no, an infinite loop will not wear out your cpu or ram, but it could prevent some parts of them from entering low power modes, depending on the actual hardware an OS.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, yes. Your RAM will start getting used up. I've had this happen to me as well and sometimes I had no choice *but* to force-quit the application too.

In the case of **Sublime Text**, just use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd> to stop the execution. It may happen in certain code you write where it isn't immediately obvious that this is happening. However, you can easily check the RAM usage and you'll see it *spiking*!

Comment: Does Ctrl + break really end recursion?

Comment: @BhargavRao I don't know about recursion. The question was about infinite loops, which I imagine are more about the use of `while`. To answer you honestly, I don't see why it wouldn't. But Python will get to its maximum recursion depth faster than you can blink... so it's probably academic. BTW, how did you create the ctrl+break hotkey look? Thanks for that ;).

Comment: It is the HTML tag `<kbd>`

Comment: @BhargavRao Awesome. I'll remember that :).

Answer (score 1):

> After multiple bad attempts, I've noticed that my OS is slower. I was wondering if running loops would negatively harm the RAM or processing even though if I force quit the application - or maybe it was a coincidental occurrence.

No. Unless the application has left behind execution artifacts (such as other zombie processes which happen to loop too), nothing will happen (after the execution of the process stops, the operating system reclaims all the resources it held).

> I was wondering if running loops would negatively harm the RAM or processing even though if I force quit the application

As far as the CPU is concerned, an infinite loop is just a set of never ending (conditional or unconditional) jumps, that may or may not be followed by other meaningful instructions. It's completely harmless.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning than usually running an infinite loop will consume 100% of one core -- so heating the processor unit. If your hardware has [CPU throttling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling) this might result in a (temporary) lowering the whole CPU frequency -- thus affecting all processes running on the computer.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Oh, sure. I totally agree with you. I just interpreted this question as "Will it have negative consequences in the longer term?"

Answer (score -1):

Once the process/thread in which the loop was executing is destroyed, then the loop execution is also terminated.

There may be cleanup of resources that might need to still occur, which could have an 'impact' on depending on how those resources were managed... As far as I know python performs all the necessary cleanup preventing memory leaks, etc